# Extreme of function - geometry

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I am helping with one homework assignment.

Two corridors of width 320 cm and 135 cm are intersecting each other with angle of 90 degrees. Find the maximum length of thin non-flexible (unbending) stick which can be transfered from one coridor to another.

It should be related with extreme of function i.e. first derivative but somehow I do not see what should be derived since both dimensions (lengths) are given and I do not have good idea how to express the length of stick. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Please, give me the answer ! Cheers.

Comment: Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a stick that is *too long*, at the moment it gets stuck, it looks like this:

[image]

If you let $x$ be the length along the bottom wall from the corner over to where the red stick touches the wall, and let $f(x)$ be the length of the stick that would get stuck there (going one way or the other), you should be able to find a minimum.

Draw a figure, use the Pythagorean theorem for all it's worth to construct $f$, differentiate, and solve.

Comment: I am really waiting for the solution. This is the simplest variation of the so-called "sofa problem" the (even approximated solution) of which I never understood. Cheers.

Comment: Denote widths of corridors d1 and d2 and length of stick c. Also denote part of the wall on the bottom part which is wider than d1 x and on the left part y (upper part). Then you have: c^2 = (x+d1)^2 + (y+d2)^2 . Let alpha be tha angle of the stick to horizontal wall. You can say x=d2/tan(alpha) and y=d1*tan(alpha). Now you have c as a function of alpha and you can derive by it.

Comment: @user120250. Thank you very much ! Cheers.